# Como formatar string de número com .net core?

Tags: html, razor, .net-core

Preciso formatar essa string de número, que é retornada de uma api:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu quero: 83.951.583.

Página Razor:

```
<h3>Mundo</h3>

<div class="card bg-primary text-white mb-3" style="max-width: 14rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-text">Casos confirmados</h5>
    <h3>@Model.Global.TotalConfirmed</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você já testou alguma dessas opções> https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: Tentei, mas não consegui implementar em página razor.

Comment: Olá Eduardo. Use `$@String.Format('{0:c}', <valor vai aqui>)` com o parametro `'c'`, como explicado em https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN ... troque o `<valor vai aqui>` pelo valor que deseja passar do seu Model.

Comment: Consegui de outra forma. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é simples é só utilizar o `toString("N0")` [com N que formata em número e o zero que retira a parte decimal](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) e também para colocar a cultura do Brasil especifique no segundo parâmetro:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR")
```

sendo que esse valor seja do tipo inteiro (`int`) o número.

---

***Exemplo de código final***:

```
int c = 83600952;
string r = c.ToString("N0",
              System
             .Globalization
             .CultureInfo
             .CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR")
           );
```

[Exemplo OnLine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QbPnNH)

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Cadeias de caracteres de formato numérico padrão](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)</sup>